# DateTime is not parsing string to date

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using DateTime construcor to construct date but it is not parsing, mine code is following

```
  $current=$timeDate->nowDate(); 

//$timeDate->nowDate() is sugarCRM function returns date and in next line i fetched variables $y, $m, $d successfully 

  list($y, $m, $d) = explode("/", $current);
  $expiredate = new DateTime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d);
```

following error caught in exception

```
DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (08-30-2012) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the variables ($y, $m, $d) seems to be off, you should write

```
list($m, $d, $y) = explode("/", $current);
```

Comment: yes i corrected it , thank's alot. In fact i know the order but i was fetching variables in wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a more straightforward approach, you can use:

```
$current = new DateTime('now');
$expiredate = $current->format('Y-m-d');
```